# Nginx Lua regex match first word

Tags: regex, nginx, lua, lua-patterns

I try to convert regex into Lua language, from

```
([a-zA-Z0-9._-/]+)
```

to

```
^%w+?([_-]%w+)
```

I want to make match first word with '-' and '_':

```
mar_paci (toto totot)
toi-re/3.9
pouri marc (sensor)
Phoenix; SAGEM
```

The result:

```
marc_paci
toi-re
pouri marc
Phoenix
```

The code used:

```lua
value = string.match(ngx.var.args, "^%w+?([_-]%w+)")
```

In the `^%w+?([_-]%w+)` regex, I added the `?` character for an optional string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```lua
^[%w%s_-]*%w
```

It matches

- `^` - start of string
- `[%w%s_-]*` - zero or more alphanumerics, whitespaces, `_` or hyphens
- `%w` - an alphanumeric char.

See the [Lua demo](https://ideone.com/qzCZAE):

```lua
local function extract(text)
    return string.match(text, "^[%w%s_-]*%w")
end
 
print(extract("mar_paci (toto totot)"))
-- => mar_paci
print(extract("toi-re/3.9"))
-- => toi-re
```

Comment: Thanks for your replying, it is because I find new use case, so regex changed :) I edit the question with more example

Comment: @marcooo_i I updated the solution.